# Intel graphics HD4000 fails to work

Tags: intel-graphics

*This question may be marked as duplicate but questions I've found alike in askubuntu stackoverflow ubuntuforum can not solve this problem or give me an answer.*

The model of my laptop is Acer V7-481 which comes with an **i3-3227U** CPU and **NO graphic card**.

When I was installing ubuntu 12.04 for the first time, the laptop booted up in a black screen

The only solution to this is to add a boot parameter `nomodeset` or something to disable the KMS.

Other solutions I found are useless, including `acpi` related and adjust the backlight using shortcuts etc.

Now, my laptop can **only** boot with `nomodeset` but I don't think the integrated graphic card is functioning normally.

1. I cannot connect to a second monitor via HDMI and Display Port
2. unity is running in 2d mode
3. can't use 3d hardware acceleration

out put of `uname -a`

`Linux v7 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

out put of `lshw -c video`

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Comment: Why not Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @Xubu-Tur No I didn't. Should I do that? How?

Comment: Perhaps it will run better.